# FetchFailedException spark failure

Tags: apache-spark, skew

I enabled adaptive using spark 3.1 but still see some long running tasks compared to other tasks. I tried to filter most frequent keys but it didn’t help and I am getting FetchFailedException at the end. There are several joins and group by executed.

Does adaptive always handle skew joins ? What can help with FetchFailedException?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need optimize skew for join spark 3.1 but seams it doesn’t optimize it because several stages have task that run too long (around 5-10 times longer)